# How to pass a list of xpath values to a function - Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, xml, function, xml-parsing, argument-passing

I had a question about best practice for passing a list of XML xpath values to a function.

I'm just a beginner programmer and am just learning javascript.

What I want to do is define an object with criteria (done this okay), and a list of results I want back from a query, both of which that can be passed to a function.

The following is working, but I'm thinking that probably sending the xpath as the key in the object is probably not the best idea, with null values.  I get back an object from the function with the keys I sent and the values.

```
    var myCriteria = { prospect_id : 98888158, type : 13};
    var myResults = { 'total_results':null , 'visitor_activity/id':null };
    myResults = pardotQuery(authentication, 'visitorActivity', myCriteria, myResults);
```

I thought about just passing it in as an array, then converting it into an object that gets returned with keys, and values.

Please advice what would be best.

Thanks.

Comment: for what do you need the output for??

Comment: I'm using the results of my query in other parts of my program.  In this case I was just testing to see whether there was a hard bounce type of activity to a particular prospect.  I could then use myResults['total_results'] to check if there was at least one bounce activity.  THanks.

Comment: if you need to know the matches for each query than an object with query : result pairs is fine, if you only need the results and their total amount an array is good, but if you need both you can also create you own type of <Result> than contains all information. You can even use one XPathResult for all your queries and return this (the last parameter of document.evaluate() )...

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look at what a xPathResult is.  I should add this is a server side script with no user interaction so no access to the DOM.